# MS Teams app with SSO for two applications

Tags: microsoft-teams

We’d like to create an MS Teams app with static content tabs. In first tab we want to keep our custom web application with AAD authentication, in second tab we’d like to pin SharePoint site.

The web site is Front End (react) App + .NET Framework Web Api. We're using currently web based auth, but for SSO we can use client authentication with ADAL JS if necessary.

Since we’re using the same user account for Teams, our web app and SharePoint, we don’t want users to authentication again, so Single Sign On would be the perfect solution. However, we cannot find the solution that both SharePoint and our web application can use SSO, because IDs and resources are obviously different and only one set of them is supported:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso

Is there any possibility to support our configuration (two applications for SSO)?

Comment: This is not a supported scenario on teams. One Teams app maps to one AAD app and therefore one token. you could build multiple Teams apps for your scenario and use deep links to navigate between them if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Copying answer from comment for visibility.*

This is not a supported scenario on teams. One Teams app maps to one AAD app and therefore one token. you could build multiple Teams apps for your scenario and use deep links to navigate between them if required.